# How can I download several articles from my library at once from Mendeley?

Tags: mendeley

How can I download several articles from my library at once from Mendeley, directly from their website, without having to use the desktop client?

I couldn't find a way to do so:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Disclosure**: I work for Mendeley and I have been one of the developers of this web application.*

You cannot export some or all of your references into BibTex, RIS or EndNote XML the same way as you would in the desktop application.

However early 2017, a new version of the web application offered a way to export some or all of your references into the Microsoft Word Citation Manager:

> You can now export references from your Mendeley Web Library into the Microsoft Word Citation Manager — without opening your Mendeley Desktop.

If this looks useful to you, you can read more [here](https://blog.mendeley.com/2017/02/28/insert-references-into-your-paper-using-mendeleys-web-library/).

**EDIT Sept 11 2020**

It is now possible to do so with the new Mendeley Reference Manager web application:
https://www.mendeley.com/reference-manager/